# ServerAuthenticationConverter not working with aspectJ

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, aspectj

i have implemented the interface class `ServerAuthenticationConverter` which is under `org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication`

```
public class WebFilter implements ServerAuthenticationConverter {
```

i have an aspectJ class that should execute after the `convert` function, but for some reason my aspectJ does not work, it will work if i change the path to my controller,
i.e

```
    @Pointcut("execution(public  *.convert(..))")
    public void test() {
    }
    @AfterReturning(value = "test()")
    public void doP4ublish() {
// do something -> does not work
     }
```

```
    @Pointcut("execution(public  *.Controller..*(..))")
    public void test() {
    }
    @AfterReturning(value = "test()")
    public void doP4ublish() {
// do something -> this will work
     }
```

so my question why AspectJ does not work with  `ServerAuthenticationConverter`? why does it only starts working once it leaves the class.

Comment: Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: My guess is that your `WebFilter` is not registered as a Spring bean/component while your controller is. Correct?

Comment: yes, i have created webfilter with normal constructor and not with bean, i assume that's the issue